# regex rar archive

Tags: regex, bash, rar

I have this regex:

```
.*part0?0?1.rar
```

and this:

### match

```
S01.rar
S23.part1.rar
s4.part01.rar
Movie.rar
Youtube Movie.part1.rar
123Mov Ddaa.part01.rar
123Mov Ddaa.part001.rar
```

### dont match

```
S01.part02.rar
S2.part4.rar
Movie.part3.rar
Youtube Movie.part08.rar
123Mov Ddaa.part002.rar
```

i test with https://regexr.com/

How can i all the words under match match? Sry for my very very bad english :/

Comment: Are you going to use the pattern in JavaScript? regexr.com only supports JS regex flavor.

Comment: Even if you are bad in english (I'm also bad in english), try to make your question clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you want to use a regex in Bash. The regex you need will match any string containing `part` not followed with a number other than `1`, `01` or `001`, i.e. the number after `part` must be greater than `1` *and negate*  the result.

See [Bash demo](https://ideone.com/V7IzkY) printing `anything`:

```
file="Youtube Movie.part01.rar"
regex='part(0*[2-9][0-9]*|0*1[0-9]+)\.rar'
if ! [[ $file =~ $regex ]]
then
    echo "anything"
fi
```

Here, [`part(0*[2-9][0-9]*|0*1[0-9]+)\.rar`](https://regex101.com/r/BlAjkg/2) matches

- `part` - a literal substring `part`
- `(0*[2-9][0-9]*|0*1[0-9]+)` - either of the 2 alternatives:

  - `0*` - zero or more `0` chars
  - `[2-9]` - a digit from `2` to `9`
  - `[0-9]*` - any 0+ ASCII digits
  - `|` or
  - `0*1[0-9]+` - zero or more `0` chars, `1` and then one or more any digits
- `\.` - a dot
- `rar` - a `rar` substring.

The `if ! [[ $file =~ $regex ]]` means "if the `$regex` does not match the `$file`, show `anything`".

Comment: Or [**`(?=.*part0*[2-9]).+|(.+)`**](https://regex101.com/r/vk0H7I/1) and take group 1.

Comment: thank you very much. it work fine at regex101.com but dont work in my bash:

file="S01.rar"

if [[ ${file} =~ ^(?!.*\.part(?!0{0,2}1\.)[0-9]+\.rar$).+ ]]

then

    echo "match"

fi

Comment: Sry i dont know about any differences. Should i ask my question again?

Comment: @xtrars Maybe `part(0*[2-9][0-9]*|0*1[0-9]+)\.rar` will be better, it will also allow `part100` or `part011`